# jest, enzyme - testing a method that returns jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link, IndexLink} from 'react-router';

class Navbar extends Component {

  renderLinks = (linksData) => {
    return linksData.map((linkData) => {
      if(linkData.to === '/') {
        return(
          <div className="navbar-link-container" key={linkData.to}>
            <IndexLink activeClassName="navbar-active-link" to={linkData.to}>
              <i className="navbar-icon material-icons">{linkData.icon}</i>
              <span className="navbar-link-text">{linkData.text}</span>
            </IndexLink>
          </div>
        )
      }
      else {
        return(
          <div className="navbar-link-container" key={linkData.to}>
            <Link activeClassName="navbar-active-link" to={linkData.to}>
              <i className="navbar-icon material-icons">{linkData.icon}</i>
              <span className="navbar-link-text">{linkData.text}</span>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`navbar navbar-${this.props.linksData.length}`}>
        {this.renderLinks(this.props.linksData)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
  linksData: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default Navbar;
```

Now I am trying to write a unit test that will check the if condition (returning IndexLink or Link depending on the .to property):

But I can't seem to test for the exact jsx return of the function, since when I console.log one of the returns I get this:

> { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
>         type: 'div',
>         key: '/',
>         ref: null,
>         props: 
>          { className: 'navbar-link-container',
>            children: 
>             { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
>               type: [Object],
>               key: null,
>               ref: null,
>               props: [Object],
>               _owner: null,
>               _store: {} } },
>         _owner: null,
>         _store: {} }

This is the test I have written so far:

```
it('renderLinks should return a IndexLink', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar linksData={mockLinksData}/>);
    const renderLinksReturn = wrapper.instance().renderLinks(mockLinksData);
    let foundIndexLink = false;
    renderLinksReturn.map((linkHtml) => {
      console.log(linkHtml);
    });
    expect(foundIndexLink).toBe(true);
  })
```

Now I do not know what to test against to see if the function is running correctly. Is there a way to 'mount' the return of the function like a component? Or is there a simple method to return a html string of the actual return that I can check against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need to call

```
const renderLinksReturn = wrapper.instance().renderLinks(mockLinksData);
```

as it will be called when `Navbar` will be rendered.

Your solution is correct but in case you want some alternative robust ways to test it.

Since this test specifically tests for `IndexLink` and assumes that `mockLinksData` contains **to = "/"**

```
it('renderLinks should return a IndexLink when passed a link with to:\"/\"', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar linksData={mockLinksData}/>);

    // You can use both component name or component displayname
    // IndexLink or "IndexLink"
    expect(wrapper.find('IndexLink')).to.have.length(1);

    // In case you want to test whether indexLink has appropriate props or classes.
    const indexLink = wrapper.find(IndexLink).first();

   // Check whether indexLink has pass prop
   expect(indexLink.props().to).to.equal("/");

   // Check whether indexLink has correct classes set.
   expect(indexLink.hasClass('navbar-active-link')).to.equal(true);

  // Check whether indexLink displays the link test correctly
  expect(indexLink.find('navbar-link-text').text()).to.equal(mockLinksData.text);


 });
```

Comment: The thing about this is that I test whether or not the method gets called in another test. So I thought that the best practice was to test methods separately, so if for some reason I need to update the method, the test results will more correctly pinpoint the problem? Or am I just overcomplicating things? It is also important to note that his is the first test that I am writing, I will also test for the correct html output, passing an empty object, etc.

Comment: In that case you can wrap up the jsx returned by that method into a separate component and write test cases for it separately. But any approach is okay as long as you test all aspect of your component either visual or functionality wise.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I need to refactor the method into separate functions anyway, and once the functions have a single input and return, it should be much easier to test.

Answer (score 21):

Faced similar issue where we were passing a jsx component to another component as a prop.

You can **shallow render the returned jsx** since it's like a valid React Function/Stateless Component.
eg:

```
const renderLinks = shallow(wrapper.instance().renderLinks(mockLinksData))
```

And continue with your usual enzyme assertions.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. So obvious and easy to miss. +1.

Answer (score 8):

To build on top of @Nachiketha 's answer, that syntax won't work when what's returned is a `fragment`, this can be solved by wrapping the result in a `div` like:

```
const renderLinks = shallow(<div>
    {wrapper.instance().renderLinks(mockLinksData)
    </div>
)}
```

as suggested in [this tread](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1213).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the type of the element is stored in the object. So the condition is:

```
props.children.type.displayName
```

And the final test I wrote looks like this for IndexLink:

```
it('renderLinks should return a IndexLink when passed a link with to:\"/\"', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar linksData={mockLinksData}/>);
    const renderLinksReturn = wrapper.instance().renderLinks(mockLinksData);
    let foundIndexLink = false;
    renderLinksReturn.map((linkHtml) => {
      {linkHtml.props.children.type.displayName === 'IndexLink' ? foundIndexLink = true : null};
    });
    expect(foundIndexLink).toBe(true);
  });
```